# How do I get rid of the KDE Dolphin file/folder details on mouseover?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, settings, dolphin

The popup/preview window in KDE Dolphin (17.04.03) keeps opens up as soon as I hover my mouse over a file or folder and I can't figure out where the settings are to disable it.

[image: This is what I'm talking about]

How do I disable it, or increase the time between mouse-hover and its displaying?

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1027502/edit) your question to include the version of Dolphin?

Comment: @DKBose Made the edit. It's 17.04.03.

Comment: @DKBose I'm running Kubuntu 17.10. Dolphin is at 4:17.04.3-0ubuntu2. There's no later version available in the repo.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. My bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dolphin tooltips**

Dolphin Handbook: F1

[image]

Online: https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/dolphin/index.html

From the handbook:

> Chapter 3. Configuring Dolphin
>
> The Dolphin Preferences Dialog
>
> The Preferences Dialog is opened via Settings → Configure Dolphin...
>   in the menu in Dolphin's main window...
>
> General
>
> This group contains settings which control the general behavior of
>   Dolphin...
>
> **When hovering over a file or folder with the mouse, a small window
>   with relevant information is shown if Show tooltips is enabled.**

[image]

Comment: `a small window with relevant information is shown` - I still find that window *huge* in Dolphin 21.08. By the way, the same info can be shown by selecting "Information": adding a toolbar button for it or using F11 (keys are editable).